# Losing log file after restart (log4j)

Tags: java, logging, log4j, jonas

I am using log4j to show log in my java application. I use the DailyRolligFileAppender to rolling the log file. It works well until I do a manuel restart. I will lose the last log file when the application is restarted. log4j will take this file, overwrite it, put two line of log, then  create a new file and write into. So I lose the last file.

For example : I have

> App.log.2015-10-09 
>   App.log.2015-10-10 (last restart) 
>   App.log.2015-10-11 
>   App.log.2015-10-12

Let's suppose that the last restart was in 2015-10-10. If i restart the app in 
2015-10-12 , then log4j will overwrite the content of App.log.2015-10-10 file, writing into these lines :

> App - 12 Oct2015 10:18:31,960 DEBUG -- [PropertyMessageResources] 
>   App - 12 Oct 2015 10:18:31,972 DEBUG --[ActionServlet] Finalizing this controller servlet
>   App - 12 Oct 2015 10:18:31,977 INFO  -- [GraniteConfigListener] GraniteDS stopped

Then it will close this file and create a new file normally named `App.log` which will write the current log.

this is my log4j.xml :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<!-- ALL < DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL < OFF -->

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
 debug="false">

 <!-- ********** APPENDERS DEFINITION (begin) ********** -->
  
 <appender name="exp_FILE_APPENDER" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="/data1/nom_app/logs/app.log" />
  <param name="Append" value="true" />
  <param name="DatePattern" value=".yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern"
    value="nom_app - %d{DATE} %-5p %X{Batch}-%X{idSession}-%X{idRequete} [%c{1}] %m%n" />
  </layout>
 </appender>
  
 

  
 
 <!-- Delia -->
 <logger name="nom_package">
  <level value="DEBUG" />
 </logger>

 <!-- appender -->
 <root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="exp_FILE_APPENDER" /> 
 </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Can you please tell me how should I do to avoid the lose of the log file.

Comment: Can you please add your log4j config file?

Comment: I have added my conf file